# Fractional part of $n\alpha$ is equidistributed

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, ergodic-theory, equidistribution

> Let $\alpha$ be an irrational number. Then the sequence $\{\{n\alpha\}\}$ is equidistributed.

I am using the following definition of equidistribution. A sequence $\{a_i\}$ is equidistributed if $\frac1n\sum\limits_{i=1}^n f(a_i) \to \lambda(f):=\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx$ for all continuous $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$.

In the proof I used the fact that if $T_g(x)=(g+x) \pmod 1$, then $\lambda(f\circ T_g)=\lambda(f)$ for all continuous $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$. Hence $\lambda$ is the unique Haar probability measure.

Now suppose for $\theta=e^{2i\pi\alpha}$ I have proved
$$\frac1n\sum\limits_{i=1}^n g(\theta^i) \to \hat{\lambda}(g)$$
for all continuous $g:T\to \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ where $\hat{\lambda}$ is the unique haar measure in $T$ and $T$ is the circle group.

Then how to deduce the fact that $n\alpha \pmod 1$ is equidistributed. Note that if we define the map $G: [0,1)\to T$ as $G(x)=e^{2i\pi x}$. Then $f=g\circ G$ does not covers all continuous functions.

Comment: The search term for what you are looking at is "Weyl criteria". The idea is that the exponential functions are dense in the continuous functions.

Comment: Yes I am aware about Weyl's criterion. I was trying to prove this equidistribution result without using it. I get that the set containing all linear combinations of $e^{itx}$ as $t$ varies in $\mathbb{R}$ is a self adjoint algebra that separates points and vanishes at no point. Hence its uniform closure has all contnuous functions from $[0,1]\to \mathbb{C}$. Can you please give a little more hint

Comment: I think what you are trying to do is prove Weyl's criterion. You know the sum converges to the integral for exponential functions, and you know the exponential functions are dense in the continuous functions, so you put these together to make an argument that the sum converges to the integral for continuous functions. The argument should be in any source that gives a proof of Weyl.

Comment: @GerryMyerson You probably meant the "trigonometric polynomials" are dense in the continuous functions.

Comment: @i70, yes, I think what I had i mind was the set of linear combinations of functions of the form $e^{2\pi inx}$, $n$ running through the integers.