# average of $\{n\alpha \}$, where $\alpha$ irrational

Tags: real-analysis, irrational-numbers, fractional-part

Let $\alpha$ be an irrational number.

Let $\{x\}$ denote the fractional part of $x$.

Is it true that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\{\alpha \}+\{2\alpha \}+\{3\alpha \}+\cdots+\{n\alpha \}}{n}=\frac{1}{2}$.

How to prove it? Thank you.

Comment: In the following book: https://books.google.co.in/books?id=bRr2IvwTJaEC&pg=PA101&lpg=PA101&dq=average+of+fractional+part+of+na,+a+irrational&source=bl&ots=g-X0ZPVMVg&sig=QMHMJIEs_yHRrlZQBVljjE2z-7U&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi9vdy3yNzQAhUGs48KHRSpDb4Q6AEIKzAD#v=onepage&q=average%20of%20fractional%20part%20of%20na%2C%20a%20irrational&f=false, look up page 101, there is a  theorem by three mathematicians, which is more remarkable than your result. There's a proof as well!

Comment: For any bounded continuous function $f$, and any real irrational $\alpha$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1/n)\sum_{k=1}^nf(\{\,k\alpha\,\})$ exists and equals $\int_0^1f(x)\,dx$. This happens because the sequence $\{\,k\alpha\,\}$, $k=1,2,\dots,$ is "uniformly distributed", and it goes by the name of "the Weyl criterion". The special case, $f(x)=x$, answers the question.

Comment: Any thoughts, Bless, about what's been written in the comments?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP has abandoned it.

Comment: See also [Equidistribution theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistribution_theorem) and [Fractional part of $n\alpha$ is equidistributed](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1348104)