# Fourier series and integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I have a problem proving this.

If $f$ is a continuous, piecewise smooth function defined on $\mathbb{R}$ and $2\pi$-periodic, with $\frac{\alpha }{\pi }$ irrational, we have to show that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=0}^nf(x+\alpha j)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(t)~\mathrm{d}t$$

for all $x$. Does anyone have a lead to help get me started on the demonstration?

Comment: What is $\alpha$?

Comment: the RHS does not appear to depend upon x at all

Comment: @WW1 it does not need to, if $\alpha \neq \frac{k_1}{k_2}2\pi$ then we will be sampling pointwise uniformly over the period. It won't matter which the starting point is.

Comment: @Lorago all we know is that / is irrational

Comment: @WW1 what does that entail?

Comment: There are several postings about Weyl's equidistribution theorem in MSE. You can try a search for this type's of results in the search banner of MSE.

Comment: @OliverDíaz yes it does actually! However, I don't understand why we can assume that sup|(+ℎ)−()|≤ sup|(+ℎ)−()|, any idea on that?

Comment: @nancy: I think you are referring to reuns' solution. I don't make any such assumptions. I suggest first to prove the result for trigonometric polynomials and then using the to continuous function using density then to all Riemann integrable functions using density of step functions, which can also be approximated by continuous functions.

Answer (score 1):

The result is true only when $\alpha$ is an irrational multiple of $2\pi$ (there are easy counterexamples otherwise).

When $\alpha$ is an irratoinal multiple, all you need to do is to use the result that $j\alpha \mod 2\pi$ is equidistributed. You can find a proof here ([Fractional part of $n\alpha$ is equidistributed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1348104/fractional-part-of-n-alpha-is-equidistributed))

Comment: Thank you so much for the input, I indeed forgot to add the hypothesis that `$\frac{\alpha }{\pi }$` is an irrational. Does the equidistribution of  mod2 still apply?

Comment: @nancy yes, it will ONLY apply if you add this hypothesis. Otherwise $\alpha j \mod 2\pi$ is a finite sequence and you can say nothing about it.